# Make a single column value from multiple rows column

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am facing a very isolated problem regarding to the `dynamic sql query`. I have two queries running on a single `stored procedure`. They are following

First query:

```
SELECT *
                FROM (
                      SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY viwPerformance.LastModifiedOn DESC) AS rowNumber,viwPerformance.* FROM viwPerformance WHERE OrgId=218 AND EmployeeId = 1668 AND IsTerminate = 0 AND TagId LIKE '%' + CAST(2893 AS VARCHAR) + '%' AND Archive='False' AND SmartGoalId IS NOT NULL
                     ) AS E
                WHERE  rowNumber >= 1 AND
                       rowNumber <  11
```

it results all the column values and the SmartGoalId as

```
4471,2815,4751,4733,4863,4690,4691,4692,4693,4694
```

And the second query (here I need only SmartgoalId from the above query so I use stuff)

```
SELECT @strGoalIds = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(SmartGoalId AS VARCHAR)
                FROM (
                      SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY viwPerformance.LastModifiedOn DESC) AS rowNumber,viwPerformance.* FROM viwPerformance WHERE OrgId=218 AND EmployeeId = 1668 AND IsTerminate = 0 AND TagId LIKE '%' + CAST(2893 AS VARCHAR) + '%' AND Archive='False' AND SmartGoalId IS NOT NULL
                     ) AS E
                 WHERE  rowNumber >= 1 AND
                       rowNumber <  11 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

and it's results the SmartgoalId as

```
4471,2815,4751,4733,4863,4651,4690,4691,4692,4693
```

Please note that the last id "4694" is not available from above query as the "4651"is added to it but it's not available from first query and this is correct that "4651" should not be in the second query result.

So my main point is why the second query gives different results as it's the same as the first query.

Note: Am I right that the `Stuff` function reversing the values and not giving them in correct order.

Comment: Are you sure your data hasn't changed in between?

Comment: Are you sure that your sort criteria on viwPerformance.LastModifiedOn is unique?  If there are multiple rows with the same value this query can potentially give you different results each time.

Comment: @podiluska: Yes, I am sure as it's the value from local development environment and I am not performing any operation which will change the value of LastModifiedOn.

Comment: @Dan: I think you are right I noticed that in some columns the date field value for LastModifiedOn is same. Is it the real cause of problem? What will be the correct and quick solution for this?

Comment: That would do it--see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have some rows with the same value for LastModifiedOn it depends how you want to handle ties.

If you want this query to always return the 10 most "recent" rows but always return the same ones when there are ties you can add another column to your `ORDER BY viwPerformance.LastModifiedOn DESC` clause that will make the sort unique and unchanging, like:

```
ORDER BY viwPerformance.LastModifiedOn,viwPerformance.SmartGoalId DESC)
```

Comment: Edited to use SmartGoalId as the secondary sort column.